# Sending variables from one PHP page to another

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I'm building a quiz web application that is dynamically generated from a database on my server.  I have pretty much implemented all the functionality, the only missing piece is making it capable of providing multiple quizzes.  Right now I have to manually write in the code `$quiz_id = 1, $quiz_title = "geography"` in the quiz.php script for it to run correctly.  If I can generate the values for these two variables my quiz.php would work for multiple quiz topics.

So, herein lies my problem: I'd like the user to be able to choose from a list of quiz topics (on the page quizlist.php), click on the link of the quiz they want to take, and then bring them to a page with the quiz questions/choices (on the page quiz.php).  Additionally, I'd like to send some values from quizlist.php to quiz.php associated with the specific link the user clicked.  I'd like to send the quiz_id and quiz_title to the page quiz.php in order to present the correct set of questions.

I believe there is a way to do this using $_GET or $_POST, as well as using $_SESSION.  **My questions is which way is better?  And how do I do it?**  I hear $_SESSION is more secure but I'm not sure if I am really worried about this data (quiz_id and quiz_title) being secure.

Currently, here is the code for quizlist.php

```
<?php
  // Start the session
  require_once('startsession.php');

  // Insert the page header
  $page_title = 'Quiz List';
  require_once('header.php');

  require_once('connectvars.php');

  // Make sure the user is logged in before going any further.
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    echo '<p class="login">Please <a href="login.php">log in</a> to access this page.</p>';
    exit();
  }

  // Show the navigation menu
  require_once('navmenu.php');

  // Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  // Determine number of quizes based on title in quiz table
  $query = "SELECT * FROM quiz";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  // Loop through quiz titles and display links for each
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo '<a href="quiz.php">' . $row['title'] . '</a><br />';
  }

  mysqli_close($dbc);

  // Insert the page footer
  require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could use sessions for making "global" variables.

Comment: Tackle one problem at a time first the list of question working then the authentication. You should use GET because SESSION is for things specific to a  given user. POST is for code that modifies the server side (here you only load things from the database). And GET is to retrieve server-side information which is exactly your case.

Comment: Thank you for the precise breakdown of $_SESSION, $_POST, and $_GET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$_GET`.

First, you're going to want to change this line

```
echo '<a href="quiz.php">' . $row['title'] . '</a><br />';
```

To something like this:

```
echo '<a href="quiz.php?id='.$row['id'].'">' . $row['title'] . '</a><br />';
```

And then in `quiz.php`, retrieve the appropriate quiz using `$_GET['id']` as your primary key to look it up in the database.

You should store your quiz title there too (in the db).

`$_GET` is appropriate here because you're just using an ID to determine which quiz to display. There's no need for confidentiality here. You would use `$_POST` when you're submitting form data which alters the database. `$_SESSION` is useful for storing basic login info and other stuff that must persist across multiple pages for the life of the session, such as wizard forms.

Answer (score 2):

To "send" values from one PHP page to another, you can use sessions or GET variables sent in the url.

Sessions:

```
$_SESSION["quiz_id"] = 1;
$_SESSION["quiz_title"] = "geography";
```

URL: `mypage.php?quiz_id=1&quiz_title=geography`

```
$quiz_id = $_GET["quiz_id"];
$quiz_title = $_GET["quiz_title"];
```

To send values from the client to the server, you will have to use an HTML form or AJAX.

Comment: Yes, he can use `$_SESSION` to pass that stuff across pages, but why would he even be passing those values? They're hard-coded!

Comment: Why would you use session in that case?

Comment: In his situation, he probably should not use sessions. I was just showing how to use them, as that was part of his question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, tackle one problem at a time first the list of question working then the authentication.

You should use GET because:

- `$_SESSION` is to store things specific to a given user its behaviour and authentication information such as a token.
- `$_POST` is for code that modifies the server side (here you only load things from the database).
- `$_GET` is to retrieve server-side information which is exactly your case.

Here loading a question is not something that should be different from one user to another.
It will not directly modify something on the server-side.
This is why you should use GET. **Using something else will work but it is not the proper way to do it.**

So basically what you change is:

```
echo '<a href="quiz.php">' . $row['title'] . '</a><br />';
```

by

```
echo '<a href="quiz.php?q_id='.$row['id'].'">' . $row['title'] . '</a><br />';
```

And in you quizz page you can now know the id of the question (stored by default in $_GET["qid"]) and do whatever you want with it.
This of course can be applied to other variables.