# passing value from one php page to another

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending variables from one PHP page to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734163/sending-variables-from-one-php-page-to-another)

I have a login page where the person enters the username and password which redirects the user to next page where the user should enter his/her employee ID to get his leave details(Query to retrieve the leave details is written).

1. What i wanted to do is when manager enters his account he should get
   the leave details of employee under him to approve or reject the
   submitted leave.
2. The manager id which is used in the first page should be used to
   retrieve the employee leave details which is in some other php page.

How to do this. I used `$_POST` method in my first page to get manager id. Is it possible to use the same value in another page ?

Comment: Can you do some google ?

Comment: Can we have some code Please !! ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$_POST` you can pass value of a field in a form to one page that it submits to.

If you need to retrieve it subsequently on more pages (like the emp id here), you should try to store the variable in [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) with are stored at client side i.e. at browser side or in [Session storage](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) in which the data is allocted memory on server itself.